# Is this question on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question about that phenomenon when two people are walking down a hallway and to avoid running into each other, go to move around the other, only to find the other person did the same thing! I'd like to ask a question about it to avoid unnecessary physical contact for this, but I'm not sure if this question will work for this site. Is this on topic?

**How can I avoid the inevitable stutter step that happens when people travel different directions in a hallway?**

Comment: I think it's on topic and can be asked here.

Comment: [The question.](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/1354/102)

Comment: @HDE226868, Yeah, I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems on-topic to me.

It is a question about avoiding the social awkwardness that comes from blocking another person's path. I don't see any reason why a question like that wouldn't be classified as an Interpersonal Skill.