# When would it be "asking too often"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been lurking around IPS and some other Stack Exchange domains for several months now, only recently having created an account and asking my [first question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8296). The thing is, I've faced many IPS issues before and had many questions I considered asking, but resisted on doing so, feeling it'd be too "generic" or "not a big deal", or having it be against the guidelines to some extent. Even with my first question, I considered for the longest time if it was really worth it posting.

Now, I don't think thinking twice before posting here is a bad thing - it is very good and recommended, in fact. My question is: **should I worry too much about what I post, or how often I post**?

I don't want to seem like I can't try to figure out IPS scenarios by myself or that I will go about asking the simplest things like "how to say thanks", but at the same time, I feel like I'll avoid posting something that would be very useful and/or important to me because I feel like it wouldn't be taken well. I've faced many conflicts over the months I've lurked here that would probably be worthy of being asked, and would have probably helped more people than just myself, but I never knew where to draw the line between "too broad/generic/unimportant" and "good enough question to be posted".

I have consulted the [on-topic](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [off-topic](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help center topics, but they seem to cover things that are explicitly off-topic, or duplicates, or opinion-based questions, not where to draw the line when a question is on-topic but might not be worthy of being asked.

Comment: The help pages are raw. For now, go thru meta questions tagged **[meta-tag:scope]** to see what's cooking.

Comment: When in doubt, you could ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) first, whether your question is suitable or not.

Comment: See also: [_Should we encourage people to just ask questions on main rather than asking about topicality on Meta?_](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1571/345)

Comment: tbh as long as your questions are good and on topic, nobody is gonna mind even if you ask them at rate limit, which is I think like 30 a month.

Comment: What Magisch said! I've only seen people on SE get annoyed by someone for asking "too many" questions in one case (apparently the user wanted to help out site stats on a lower-traffic beta), and even then meta agreed they were good and on-topic so it was fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about frequently asking questions, provided that they're good questions.

Something I used to tell my kids was:

> The only stupid question is the one you already know the answer to.

And even this isn't always a problem on SE. You're always free to answer your own questions here.

What I'm trying to say is that questions are welcome, provided that they're on topic, appropriately scoped, and about practical problems that you actually face. As long as you're asking real questions and not just asking to ask, or rep farming, frequency isn't an issue.

There is, of course, [the rate limit,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) but that's really hard to hit if you're asking real questions.

One thing that I would recommend is waiting to see how your question is received and answered before posting the next one. The comments and votes will give you some feedback on things that could be improved in your asking style before you write the next question.

This is a fairly subjective site, the things that may seem obvious to some are really difficult for others. So, the "difficulty level" of a question isn't a useful measure here. But if it's a question that you don't need an answer to, think long and hard about whether it's likely to be a question someone else will need to ask. Sometimes it's better to let people ask their own questions. Interpersonal skills being what they are, the devil is usually in the details and their details will likely differ.